# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. Windows 10

Tags: python, dll, import, netcdf4

I recently installed the last version of Python (3.6) in my new laptop and I got this error when I tried to import netCDF4 `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found`. I´m using Windows 10. Any idea about the solution?